# Broadcast a notification to all registered devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add push notification using Google Cloud Messaging to my Android application. I don't need anything fancy, I just want to notify all users of the app when certain events happen.

I don't need to notify individual users, I always want to send the notification to every user. This is an internal app with a very limited number of users, it is not distributed publicly.

Now, as far as I understand the documentation I need a registration id for every notification I want to send. I don't really want to keep track of those as I don't need to identify individual devices.

- Can I just broadcast to all devices without using any registration ids?
- If not, how can I get the registration ids of all registered devices? Do I have to keep track of those manually (outside the GCM communication)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I just broadcast to all devices without using any registration ids?

No, sorry, not at the present time.

> If not, how can I get the registration ids of all registered devices? Do I have to keep track of those manually (outside the GCM communication)?

Yes, you have to keep track of those manually (e.g., have the app send you the registration ID via a Web service).

Comment: we can send notification against topic for all registered devices without reg id

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe topic and send notification from server

Client :

```
 private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
    GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);   
    pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/global", null);    
 }
```

Server :

```
   {"to": "/topics/global","notification":{"message":"testmessage"}}
```

Comment: Limited to 1 million subscriptions per app: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30653825/1123355

Answer (score 1):

Since you're interacting with a small number of devices, you may want to consider using a service that handles the server-side complexity for you, instead of going through the effort of implementing your own. For example, [AirBop](http://www.airbop.com) is a GCM service that is free for up to 1000 devices.