# Android GCM topic subscription limit

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

With the introduction of topics in android gcm I was evaluating this option to easen the work that should be done to mantain in sync our server with some subscriptions.

However I have read in the documentation that the use of topics is limited to 1 million subscriptions. Does this mean that you can't have more than one million users (with one or more topics) or that you can only have 1 million topics subscribed (for example 100.000 users subscribed to 10 topics each) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a limit on subscriptions in your app in total, across all topics created within your app.

You will get a `TOO_MANY_SUBSCRIBERS` error when the number of subscriptions per app exceeds the 1 million limit.

Comment: SO you can only have 1 million topics subscribed (for example 100 000 users subscribed to 10 topics each) ?
? ? ? ? ? ? ? ??

Comment: You can split those 1 million subscriptions into however many topics you want. The point is, you can only have 1 million subscriptions per app, they can all be subscribed to 1 topic or to hundreds of different ones.

Comment: GCM removed the limit, please check this: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

Answer (score 5):

I think the limit has now been scrapped:

> GCM topic messaging allows your app server to send a message to
>   multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic. Based on
>   the publish/subscribe model, topic messaging supports unlimited
>   subscriptions per app.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

Comment: That's correct, check this out: http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.il/2015/12/google-cloud-messaging-weve-come-long.html?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=1cb848077c-Android_Weekly_184&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-1cb848077c-337844217

Answer (score 0):

You could try to work around this limit by using multiple `SENDER_IDs` when registering devices.

Since the [1 million subscriptions limit](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging#receiving_topic_messages_on_the%20_android_client_app) is enforced application-wide, I'm pretty sure that Google's way of tracking that is via the `SENDER_ID`.

And then, on the server-side, you'd have to issue multiple `publish` requests to GCM (each time with a different `Server API Key`, to support more than 1 million devices).

I'm going to test this theory out and let you know what I find. The worst-case scenario is that it is enforced via the application's package name (`com.example.package`), and then there is no elegant workaround.

**Update:** The limit  has now been removed!

> We’re now happy to announce that we’re allowing unlimited free topics for your app. This means app developers can place an unlimited number of devices within each topic and create an unlimited number of topics.

http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.il/2015/12/google-cloud-messaging-weve-come-long.html?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=1cb848077c-Android_Weekly_184&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-1cb848077c-337844217

Comment: Did you manage to test this Elad and what were your results? I think that 1 million is actually tiny given today's uses of smartphones.

Comment: Haven't been able to finish the test -- it takes about 2 seconds per "subscribe" request to the GCM server, so it would take around 23 days to perform the test (about 3 with parallelization), which requires issuing 1,000,000 subscribe requests to the GCM server.

Answer (score 0):

GCM now removed the limit, check this: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

Also Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) the same. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

> GCM topic messaging allows your app server to send a message to
>   multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic. Based on
>   the publish/subscribe model, **topic messaging supports unlimited
>   subscriptions per app**. The app server sends messages with payloads up
>   to 2KB to the topic, and GCM handles the message routing and delivers
>   the message reliably to the right devices. For example, users of a
>   weather forecasting app could opt in to a "severe weather alerts"
>   topic and receive notifications of storms threatening specified areas.

Answer (score 0):

Topic messaging supports unlimited topics and subscriptions for each app.

Check This 
[FCM Notifications][1]https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging