# Topics on Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Is there any constraints about number of different topics for Firebase Cloud Messaging in one app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nope. Seeing that FCM has GCM as its core, there is no limit in the number of Topics for any app. There used to be a 1 million limit, but it was removed. You can refer to this [Google Developers Blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2015/12/google-cloud-messaging-weve-come-long.html?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=1cb848077c-Android_Weekly_184&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-1cb848077c-337844217) for that.

Also, when creating a Topic in FCM, it could take up to 24 hours for it to be show up in the Firebase Console, as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37367292/4625829). Cheers! :D

Comment: I thought that story for removing 1 milion limit was for the number of subscribers per one topic, not for number of different topics

Comment: Well. Technically, its a total of a million subscribers to a single app, regardless of the number of topics. But the limitation is already scrapped.

Comment: Now that I've noticed, since technically, FCM is similar to GCM when it comes to topics, your post may be a duplicate or just similar to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30637418/4625829). Have you seen it before?

Comment: No, I haven't see that, but now I see that's helpful. Thanks mate.

Comment: So you mean. When I subscribe or create a topics, it will take one day to work?

Comment: @WaiYanHein No. As soon as there is a single subscriber for the topic, it can be used immediately. But if you're going to use the Firebase console, it will take time for it to be visible in the options.

Answer (score 2):

No I don't think so!

> Based on the publish/subscribe model, topic messaging supports unlimited subscriptions for each app. You compose topic messages as needed, and Firebase handles message routing and delivering the message reliably to the right devices. [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)

Seems like you can create topics when you need them!