# What is the max topics for Topic Messaging of FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android app that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging. For the back-end, I am using ASP.NET MVC.

I am using [Topics Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) to push notifications to multiple devices. I will create topics dynamically.

In my use-case, I dynamically create a topic from admin panel. Then users will subscribe to that topic at the client side (Android). I will push the notifications to the subscribed users of that topics, but my application may have thousands of topics.

My question is, is there any limitation for the number of topics for Topic Messaging in FCM? It may work during development with few numbers of topics, but I am worried that maybe it may hit a number of topics limitation when my application goes live.

Comment: One app instance can be subscribed to no more than 2000 topics.
If you are using batch import to subscribe app instances, each request is limited to 1000 app instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, No.

There is no limit to the number of topics that you can create. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37848400/4625829).