# FCM Topic Message doesn't appear on Console

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

The FCM Topic creation takes way too long to appear in Console (**14h** to appear on Console). Does it mean that sending messages to that topic will also take the same time? I mean a client (Android app) subscribing to that topic has to wait for long to receive data (notification)?

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("MyTopic");
```

I have read [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/11) but unable to carve out my answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830098/topics-on-firebase-cloud-messaging).

> As soon as there is a single subscriber for the topic, it can be used immediately. But if you're going to use the Firebase console, it will take time for it to be visible in the options.