# Firebase topics still showing in console after unsubscribing

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been using Firebase topics to handle notifications in my app, but I had noticed that even after unsubscribing from these topics through the app that they are still showing up in the console and can still be selected to send a notification to. I tested the topic by sending a message to it through console and it was not received, so that led me to believe that the topics are in fact deleted, but just showing. I know that Firebase should automatically delete topics when there are no more subscribers, but is that reflected in console? Or does console show a history of topics that were subscribed to at some point?

I appreciate your input. Thank you.

Comment: ["..when creating a Topic in FCM, it could take up to 24 hours for it to be show up in the Firebase Console."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37848400/4625829), it's possible that it could also take the same time for unused topics to reflect.

Comment: Would appreciate it if you could confirm the behavior above and let me know here. Cheers!

Comment: Hey @AL. ! Thank you very much for your reply. I will definitely wait this out and come back to confirm as i am very curious about this myself! Thanks again

Comment: hey @AL. So it has been well over 24 hours and it seems that topics i know i had unsubscribed to are still showing in the firebase console. Starting to think it might just display a history of topics that were once subscribed to! Not sure though! Thanks again for your reply

Comment: Thanks for the update. Strange that it's still showing up. I'll try having a test on one of my projects as soon as I have the time. Cheers!

Comment: @AL. No problem at all! If you happen to remember after running a test and get different results, please let me know! I would be interested in learning if either i am doing something wrong, or if you get the samw results as me. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hey @ACerts. Sorry it took a while. Could confirm that the topic still stays listed even after unsubscribing the device.

Comment: Hey @AL. !! No need to apologize! I am really grateful you remembered to get back to me. Thank you for your findings. I hope that this is changed in the future. It would be nice to see topics gone after unsubscribing. Thanks again and happy new year.