# Send notifications with Google Cloud Messaging without a Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, https, google-cloud-messaging

I'm looking for a method to send notifications with Google Cloud Messaging using javascript from my pc, so without a middle server. As pointed in the Developer's web site, the format of the request should be like this:

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

First I've tryed to use the ajax method:

```
var textNotification={ 
    "notification": {
        "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
        "text": "5 to 1"
    }
};
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
        type : "POST",
        headers :
        {
            'Authorization' : 'AIzaSyZ-1u...',
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        data : textNotification
    }
    ).done(function (data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
    );
```

As aspected, due to the fact I'm trying to send an HTTPS request from my PC, it is blocked. Is there another way to follow?

Comment: How about trying your code in a Google Chrome Extension?

Answer (score 0):

To send a message, you need to know the Registration ID of the device that should get the message. The application of the device gets this ID when it registers to GCM. Once the app receives this ID, it passes it to your server. So when you use your PC as a server, you will find it difficult to send the registration ID from your app unless you are running a local web-server on your PC. Your Android device and your PC should be connected to the internet by the same network. But you can also copy the registration ID manually and paste it into your code that sends the GCM messages.

You need your server to implement a service that accepts registration IDs from your app, and stores them in a database. HTTP request would only allow downstream and you need to use XMPP to do up/downstream.

You can use this [gcm sender application](https://gcm.codeplex.com/) to test your gcm-client in phone. See also the sample code [here](https://github.com/spurdow/gcm-client-library).

Comment: I want to broadcast messages to all the devices of the app. So I think I have to know all the devices IDs. Right?

Comment: Yes. Please refer here: [Broadcast a notification to all registered devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141884/broadcast-a-notification-to-all-registered-devices)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var textNotification={ 
        "notification": {
            "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
            "text": "5 to 1"
        },
        "to":"[Device Key]"
    };
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
            type : "POST",
            headers :
            {
                'Authorization' : 'key=AIzaSyZ-1u...',
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            data : textNotification
        }
        ).done(function (data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
        );
```

you need to pass `key=[Your Key]` in `Authorization`